# Duda en código para mejorar el formato

Tags: php, pdo

Saludos amigos tengo una duda tengo dos tablas:

**Trasvolares:** id_transvalores, monto, fecha, id_usuarios

Que es para ingresar montos por día, ejemplo: el admin hoy ingreso un monto de 100$.
Ahora tengo una tabla más que es **transferencias:** para qué sirve esta tabla es para realizar transferencias a clientes lo que quiero lograr es que cuando se haga una trasferencia se vaya descontando en la tabla **trasvolares;** ejemplo si tengo en trasvolares un monto de 100$ y hice una transferencia de 20$ ya me debe quedar 80$ en trasvolares.

Hasta los momentos tengo esto. Creo que me faltaría hacer un udapte para ir descontando el monto y poner una condición, cuando se llegue a un monto de 20$ me mande a recargar el trasvalor o hay otra forma de mejorar lo que se quiere

```
<!-- proceso para registrar-->
<?php
if(isset($_POST['guardar'])){

$imgFile = $_FILES['portada']['name'];
$tmp_dir = $_FILES['portada']['tmp_name'];
$imgSize = $_FILES['portada']['size'];


  $upload_dir = '../galerias_transferencias/'; // upload directory

  $imgExt = strtolower(pathinfo($imgFile,PATHINFO_EXTENSION)); // get image extension

  // valid image extensions
  $valid_extensions = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif'); // valid extensions

  // rename uploading image
  $portada = rand(1000,1000000).".".$imgExt;

  // allow valid image file formats
  if(in_array($imgExt, $valid_extensions)){     
    // Check file size '5MB'
    if($imgSize < 5000000)        {
      move_uploaded_file($tmp_dir,$upload_dir.$portada);
    }
    else{

    $errMSG = "¡ Lo siento, su archivo es demasiado grande !";
    }
    }
    else{

  $errMSG = "¡ Lo sentimos, sólo se permiten archivos JPG, JPEG, PNG y GIF !";
    }

  // si no hay errores continuo...

 $sql = "SELECT  n_transferencia FROM ordenes_de_pagos WHERE   n_transferencia = :  n_transferencia LIMIT 1"; //Creamos la select
 $check = $DB_con->prepare($sql); //Preparamos la SELECT, de ésta manera evitamos SQL Injection
 $check->bindParam(':  n_transferencia', $_POST[' n_transferencia']);//Substituimos las variables de la SELECT
 $check->execute();//Ejecutamos la consulta
 $contador = $check -> rowCount();//Esta función devuelve el número de resultados que ha devuelto la SELECT
 if ($contador > 0) {
 $check->closeCursor();

          $errMSG = "¡ Ups Aviso: El Registro ya se Encuentra Insertado !";

  }
   else
  {

 $sql=$DB_con->prepare("INSERT INTO ordenes_de_pagos (n_transferencia,fecha,hora,monto_trasferido,porcentaje,ganancia,total id_usuarios,id_bancos_admin,id_ cuentas_admin,id_clientes,id_bancos,id_cuentas,portada,status) VALUES (:n_transferencia,:fecha, :hora,:monto_trasferido,:porcentaje,:ganancia,:total,:id_usuarios,:id_bancos_admin,:id_ cuentas_admin,:id_clientes,:id_bancos, :id_cuentas,:portada,:status)");
$sql->bindParam(':  n_transferencia', $_POST[' n_transferencia']);
$sql->bindParam(':fecha', $_POST['fecha']);
$sql->bindParam(':hora', $_POST['hora']);
$sql->bindParam(':monto_trasferido', $_POST['monto_trasferido']);
$sql->bindParam(':id_usuarios', $_POST['id_usuarios']);
$sql->bindParam(':id_bancos_admin', $_POST['id_bancos_admin']);
$sql->bindParam(':id_ cuentas_admin', $_POST['id_ cuentas_admin']);
$sql->bindParam(':id_clientes', $_POST['id_clientes']);
$sql->bindParam(':id_bancos', $_POST['id_bancos']);
$sql->bindParam(':id_cuentas', $_POST['id_cuentas']);
$sql->bindParam(':portada', $portada);
$sql->bindParam(':status', $_POST['status']);
$sql->execute();

$successMSG ="¡ Bien Hecho: Registro Insertado Correctamente !";

    }
  }
 ?>
```

Comment: Depenndiendo como ser relacionesn transferencias y transvolares quizas un trigger en la BBDD sea una buena solucion.

Comment: gracias amigo por responder como seria tu solución y una buena eficiencia en el código

Comment: Simplemente creas un trigger que salte cuando insertas en la primera tabla y con el actualizas la otra tabla. Info sobre triggers (es sobre oracle pero para la base te puede servir)-> https://www.tutorialspoint.com/plsql/plsql_triggers.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No te recomiendo que actualices la tabla **Trasvolares** me imagino que eso que insertas es algún préstamo o gasto, entonces para mantener ese historial de gasto NO lo debes de modificar, ahora bien, me imagino que debe de existir una relación entre **transferencias** y **Trasvolares** al momento de que tu tengas que mostrar el monto actual, lo que debes de hacer es ir y seleccionar el monto original de **Trasvolares** ya que lo tengas haces esa consulta para seleccionar todas las transferencias relacionadas a ese registro, ya que los tengas sumas el total de transferencias y se lo restas al monto original ya con esto tendrías el monto actual conservando el monto original por si lo requieres en algún otro reporte o vista.

Comment: Hay una seccion dedicada a los comentarios justo debajo de la pregunta del OP. Usa esa seccion para todo lo que no sea una respuesta exacta al problema del OP en vez de aqui.